# I want this powershell script output in special pop window?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Below code was in powershell that code is successfully executed but i want that output in special 'popup window'

```
$ComputerName = $s = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem).name
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0) {
        $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}
        foreach ($Network in $Networks) {
            $IPAddress  = $Network.IpAddress[0]
            $SubnetMask  = $Network.IPSubnet[0]
            $DefaultGateway = $Network.DefaultIPGateway
            $DNSServers  = $Network.DNSServerSearchOrder
            $OutputObj  = New-Object -Type PSObject
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value $IPAddress
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SubnetMask -Value $SubnetMask
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Gateway -Value $DefaultGateway
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DNSServers -Value $DNSServers
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is there a reason for the different Powershell version tags?. Why do you insert `= $s` in the first line? Please elaborate on what you mean by _a special 'popup window'_

Comment: For instance take html document after running html document the content displaying in new window browser. Coming to power shell after running above script that output will  displays popup window .

Answer (score 0):

The most familiar data displayer in powershell is using the **Out-gridview** method:

You can do this if you want to go easy:

```bsh
$ComputerName = $s = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem).name
$Pop_Window = foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0) {
        $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}
        foreach ($Network in $Networks) {
            $IPAddress  = $Network.IpAddress[0]
            $SubnetMask  = $Network.IPSubnet[0]
            $DefaultGateway = $Network.DefaultIPGateway
            $DNSServers  = $Network.DNSServerSearchOrder
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value $IPAddress
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SubnetMask -Value $SubnetMask
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Gateway -Value $DefaultGateway
            $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DNSServers -Value $DNSServers

            #output the object:
            $OutputObj
        }
    }
}

$Pop_Window | Out-GridView
```

If you want to design it on your way, This would be a difficult and a messy task to do in powershell, since you always will have to call **System.Windows.Forms** class and its sub classes like Labels,Buttons,Texts and more.